# C# WebRequest Post Array with same key

Tags: c#

I need to post data to a REST service and it needs to accept post data such as

```
profile=high&profile=low
```

I am currently doing this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> postData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
postData.Add("source=", streamSource);
postData.Add("ipvs=", "false");
postData.Add("stream=", string.Empty);
postData.Add("output=", "high");
postData.Add("framerateDivider=", "1");
postData.Add("resolution=", "1");
postData.Add("profile=", "high");
postData.Add("&output=", "low");
postData.Add("&framerateDivider=", "1");
postData.Add("&resolution=", "1");
postData.Add("ipvsProfile=", "high");
postData.Add("ipvsTitle=", string.Empty);
postData.Add("ipvsDescription=", string.Empty);
postData.Add("ipvsTagName=", string.Empty);
postData.Add("ipvsTagValue=", string.Empty);

using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> data in postData)
        {
            if (data.Key.StartsWith("&"))
            {
                writer.Write(data.Key.Substring(1), data.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                writer.Write(data.Key + data.Value);
            }
        }

        writer.Close();
    }

    stream.Close();
}
```

I get a 409 conflict returned from the service and looking at it's logs it needs it is missing the second profile key.

Is there another way to Post data using WebRequest?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be `writer.Write(data.Key + "=" + data.Value);` It's hard to say because we don't know what your KeyValuePair looks like.

Comment: Updated question to include Dictionary<string, string>.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the dictionary to a list of Tuple to avoid duplicate key's... which is not the actual problem. The 409 was because of a custom Content-Type in the headers.